# Blurry image issue with Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Good day,

I'm wondering what's the issue causing my image to be so blurry. (It's not meant to be pixelated)

On the documents, they mentioned the maximum texture dimensions to be 1024 x 1024.

[Blurry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiKn4.png)

This is what I currently have at the moment. The original dimensions are 1024 x 11518.

When imported it becomes 1024 x 91

Is it because of the auto compression settings or is there some sort of limitation?

The idea was to have this long image scroll leftwards when I hit record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All textures in Spark should be square and in a power of 2 format. It looks like your image is way too big. Maximum resolution for any single texture is 1024x1024. Also, check your image compression settings inside of Spark.

Please read and follow the guidelines here for more info: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/docs/textures-and-materials/using-textures/